# Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, ipad, provisioning, xcode3.2

I've just enrolled in the iOS dev program. I've an iPad2 running iOs 5.1.1 and am developing in XCode3.2.6.
I've gone through the steps to get a provisioning profile and use my iPad for development but it's not working... in XCode I see an iOS code signing Identity listed now but on trying to run on the device I get:

> No provisioned iOS device is connected. Please check the Organizer to
>   view the status of any connected devices.

My device shows yellow in the Organize screen with message:

> The version of iOS on XXXXX does not match any of the versions of
>   iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK.
>   Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or
>   update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.
>
> OS Installed on XXXXX
>   5.1.1 (9B206)
>
> Xcode Supported iOS Versions Latest
>   4.3 (8F190)
>   4.2
>   4.1
>   4.0
>   4.0.2
>   4.0.1
>   3.2
>   3.2.2
>   3.2.1
>   3.1
>   3.1.3
>   3.1.2

I assume it's some incompatibility between iOS version and SDK but what am I supposed to do?  The organizer screen seems to let me change iOS but asks me where to find the file image, which I don't have. And I don't know how or where to install a different SDK.

Sorry if I explained this badly, I'm pretty lost here. Although I have my app working in the simulator I really don't follow all this provisioning/profile stuff even after reading through the starter guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Xcode is too old. You must upgrade to at least XCode 4.3. But to upgrade to XCode 4.3, your mac need to be running Lion. It's a hassle, but after that, you will be able to build for your iPad that is currently on iOS 5. Otherwise, you need a device that is on previous version of iOS, but that's not sustainable because apple has a way of "automatically updating" your software...(or because of some careless settings, of course)

Comment: To add, you can find all the resources in your iOS developer page. https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: I've spent ages figuring out how to build all my code in XCode 3 and really don't want to have to upgrade my OS, learn XCode 4 and rebuild all the 3rd-party stuff _again_ just to check my app will run on the device. Once I can see it works I can do that but I just want to see it on my iPad! The Organizer seems to suggest I can cahnge the software version of my device, IF I have the 'software image'... can I get an iOS 4.3 image from somewhere? This is for local testing only, not planning to try distributing!

Comment: IT WILL NEVER WORK ON YOUR IPAD without you upgrading. You have to get this now. Because your iPad is running iOS5. Your version of XCode doesn't have the iOS5 SDK. The simplier way to do this is to revert your iPad into iOS4 and this is very difficult and most likely to break your iPad (since only hacking can do it. Apple doesn't allow users to revert to older versions of software on the iOS devices)

Comment: And don't worry, XCode 4 is much simpler to use than XCode 3. Trust me, no one is learning to program now is using XCode 3 anymore.

Comment: Does this mean if I upgrade my iPAd to iOS6 I'll be screwed all over again? It seems crappy an app built against an older version of iOS can't be installed... obviously if I was developing against a _newer_ version than what's on the device it would not work!

Comment: Ya, I forgot about iOS6. So basically, if you upgraded your iPad to iOS 6, then you will need to use XCode 4.5. Skip what I said about 4.3. BTW if you like the answer, please mark it. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1 Open Xcode 5 (You should have Xcode 5)

2 Choose your iPhone5 (iOS7 or +) on Device Selection in Xcode 5 for your app.

3 Close Xcode 5, and Open Xcode 4

4 Your iPhone5 with iOS7 can now be used as test device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help. Even with 5.1 and 4.5. I am not sure why. And if I don't have a second XCode installed, would this happen I wonder? If so then how to recover?